# Not Able to debug android application direclty from eclipse to device

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget

i have one doubt,i have created new project in eclipse with android 2.3.1 and try to debug directly from eclipse to device.and it's wokring well,it's debugg in device.now when i am converting that version of android 2.3.1 to GoogleApi 2.3.1 by right clicking project and changing android property.after that when i run my project i am getting such warrining kind of symbol as u can see in below image.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsEKV.png]

again when i am changing version to simple android 2.3.1 than it's get debugging from eclipse to device.

my device name is Sony Ericon Walk Man Live and ya one more thing Google API version working well when i copy apk to sd card directly and installed in device,but getting problem only when i am running from eclipse to device directly.

One another thing i noticed is that when i create a simple project than right clicking project and runing it's asking me to wether to run in device or emulator but in older one it's not even asking and directly running in emulator...in both's project manifest there is no tag like android:debuggable="true/false" also...

any one have idea what is a solution of this problem i have already insatlled device driver to pc as well.

please help me to short out this

Thanks in advance 
Aamirkhan I.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enabling USB debugging is key, but there's something else as well. Eclipse, by default, runs your application automatically after the first run. So, if you choose an emulator as your first run, Eclipse will default to run by emulator every run afterwards.To change this, go to your "Run Configurations". [image]

There will be an option to run manually or automatically. [image]

Choose "Manual" and you will prompted to choose between your emulator and device every time you decide to run. Otherwise, you can set whether to run automatically with your device or emulator.

Comment: *Shameless addition of freehand circles.*

Comment: Dude i am able to debuggg simple project wihout google api and it's runing please read my query again

Comment: And read my answer again. I'm not telling you to install Google APIs. At no point in my answer do I tell you to install Google APIs. You said that your older project launched emulator AUTOMATICALLY. Your Run Configurations differ between projects.

Comment: So while you might have your newer project set to run manually, making you choose between the emulator and device, your older project might be set to run automatically.

Comment: Your device is showing a warning. Can you tell us what it is?

Answer (score 0):

try as in this [link](http://maketecheasier.com/activate-usb-debug-on-android-device/2011/04/06)

If you already connected your mobile device with your computer via the USB cable, please unplug it from your phone, otherwise your device will prompt you a warning requesting to do so.

[image]