# Why won't Eclipse recognize my Android phone?

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging

I have the Galaxy Nexus. I turned on debugging mode and when I tried to update driver software, I got a message saying that my driver was up to date.

I'm trying to run a simple "hello world" but Eclipse doesn't recognize that my phone is connected when I try to run it...

Comment: you have to allow usb debugging on your device, if I'm not mistaken

Comment: What is your operating system? Windows, OSX or Linux? Also please add the output of "adb devices" command to your question.

Comment: Have you downloaded and installed the official USB driver ?

Comment: Hey read this this might be helpful to you http://stackoverflow.com/a/11974943/704374

Comment: check my issue here 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11271716/not-able-to-debug-android-application-direclty-from-eclipse-to-device

Comment: Is this problem happens only in Eclipse? Try `adb devices` from console, to see if you phone is connected.

Answer (score 2):

Try these three things in your devices Settings...

1. Unknown sources:  Allow installation of non-market apps.  (On my Galaxy sIII it is found under "Security")
2. Turn on USB debugging (under Developer options.  Do this before you plug your device into your computer.
3. Turn on USB tethering (on my phone it is found under "Wireless and Network" settings

Comment: Sorry, don't know what else to suggest.  Sometimes closing Eclipse helps...  This tutorial looks good (but it is for the Nexus 7).  Maybe it will help.  Good luck,  http://zacktutorials.blogspot.ca/2012/08/nexus7-android-development.html

Comment: that link made the deal, setting the USB as Camera? still can't get it, but who cares :D

Answer (score 0):

USB debugging mode should be on in your phone and if using Windows install all drivers required whereas in Mac and linux you just need to check your USB Debugging in 
`Setting->Developer options`

Comment: I already have debugging mode on and Windows says that my drivers are up to date. Still not working.