# Can't debug android on actual device?

Tags: java, android

Running ubuntu 10.4 and trying to debug on a galaxy s2. I am able to connect the USB to the computer and get the notification. Debug mode is on, on the phone and I have added the debuggable:true to the manifest file. Any tips?

Comment: What actual problem are you having?  What are you *attempting* to do?  (Debug button in Eclipse using the ADT plugin?  Manual `adb` commands?)

Comment: I got it. Had to run adb as sudo from command line.

Comment: Hmm, you shouldn't need to do that.  I have to run `adb` as root to get shell access when the phone is in recovery mode, but not for normal app debugging when booted normally.  Maybe it differs from phone to phone, though.

Answer (score 2):

You have to go in setting->application->development->usb debugging
and enable **usb debugging** in mobile device

still you are facing problem than click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11271716/not-able-to-debug-android-application-direclty-from-eclipse-to-device)

Answer (score 0):

Two ways:

Add info about you device to /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules :

Exec in console:

```
lsusb
```

find you device info (idVendor and idProduct) and add it to like /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules this:

```
# adb protocol on maguro/toro (Galaxy Nexus)
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="04e8", ATTR{idProduct}=="6860", MODE="0600", OWNER="  <username>"
```

more information you can fine here: http://source.android.com/source/initializing.html Configuring USB Access section.

Or try to run adb from sudo:

```
sudo ./adb kill-server
sudo ./adb devices
```